# Minhas notificações não estão chegando e acho que meu código pode estar correto

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, nuget

Fiz várias tentativas para enviar Notificação por Push e nenhuma delas eu consegui visualizar em meu App. Sempre pensei até agora, que eu estava errando. Mas segui dois passo a passo e vi que com os caras estava funcionando e comigo não. Então comecei a pensar o contrário, que ou o firebase não disparava corretamente ou meu equipamento, por razões até agora desconhecida, não está recebendo. Como cheguei a essa conclusão? É que quando eu starto a aplicação, coloquei break em vários pontos e no momento que sobe a app, no ***OnRegistered*** a aplicação para e lá eu pego o ***token*** gerado. Uma vez eu desregistrei e registrei e gerei uma nova mensagem e estava com o token anterior e não o novo gerado, aí quando disparei a notificação, deu erro no ***firebase*** de :

> Status da mensagem: falhou

Coloquei o token válido, deu a mensagem de **Enviado** e na App não consigo pegar. Algo está bloqueando o recebimento e não sei o que é. Desconfio do ***Security Master***, Vysor, My KNOX e etc ou do próprio ***Firebase***, mas não tenho certeza. Veja os código que eu fiz agora, que reportou tudo acima:
Classe de inicialização

```
[Application]
    public class PushNotificationAppStater : Application
    {
        public static Context AppContext;

        public PushNotificationAppStater(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) 
            : base(javaReference, transfer)
        {

        }

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();

            AppContext = this.ApplicationContext;

            //TODO: Initialize CrossPushNotification Plugin
            //TODO: Replace string parameter with your Android SENDER ID
            //TODO: Specify the listener class implementing IPushNotificationListener interface in the Initialize generic
            CrossPushNotification.Initialize<CrossPushNotificationListener>("806431458293");

            StartPushService();
        }

        public static void StartPushService()
        {
            AppContext.StartService(new Intent(AppContext, typeof(PushNotificationService)));

            if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
            {

                PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.GetService(AppContext, 0, new Intent(AppContext, typeof(PushNotificationService)), 0);
                AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)AppContext.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
                alarm.Cancel(pintent);
            }
        }

        public static void StopPushService()
        {
            AppContext.StopService(new Intent(AppContext, typeof(PushNotificationService)));
            if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
            {
                PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.GetService(AppContext, 0, new Intent(AppContext, typeof(PushNotificationService)), 0);
                AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)AppContext.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
                alarm.Cancel(pintent);
            }
        }
    }
```

Classe do listener das mensagens e status

```
public class CrossPushNotificationListener : IPushNotificationListener
    {
        public void OnError(string message, DeviceType deviceType)
        {

        }

        public void OnMessage(JObject values, DeviceType deviceType)
        {

        }

        public void OnRegistered(string token, DeviceType deviceType)
        {

        }

        public void OnUnregistered(DeviceType deviceType)
        {

        }

        public bool ShouldShowNotification()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

MainActivity

```
[Activity(Label = "App1", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }
```

Meu App.xaml.cs
public partial class App : Application
    {
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

```
    MainPage = new App1.MainPage();
}

protected override void OnStart()
{
    CrossPushNotification.Current.Unregister();
    CrossPushNotification.Current.Register();
}

protected override void OnSleep()
{
    // Handle when your app sleeps
}

protected override void OnResume()
{
    // Handle when your app resumes
}
```

}

Meu android.manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.global.app.br" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <application android:label="App1.Android" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <service
        android:name=".Messaging.FirebaseIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

O restante tem o ***google-services.json*** com opção de build para ***google-services.json*** e o pacote instalado é:
***Xam.Plugin.PushNotification***
***NewtonSoft.json***

Esse foram os únicos plugins instalados por mim. O que pode ser esse problema?

Comment: Por acaso você testou receber a notificação com o app em background ???

Comment: @pnet onde estão os receivers declarados no manifest? Onde estão as classes dos receivers e services do firebase??? Remova tudo do seu projeto e siga exatamente o que está escrito [neste guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-fcm/) da documentação do Xamarin. Fiz por ele e funcionou certinho. Porém aqui ele faz o tipo de notificação base, depois tem que ver para implementar sua própria notificação.

Comment: @GrupoCDSInformática, já tentei fazer por esse exemplo, mas estava dando pau ao tentar instalar essa referencia: **Xamarin.Google.Play.Services.Base**, dizia que não dava para instalar num projeto Mono.Droid acho, inclusive tenho um post respondido pelo ***LINQ***. Eu uso Xamarin.Forms, mas vou fazer um outro projeto do zero com esse exemplo. Você ou o Colleta me falaram se eu havia instalado o google-services ou algo assim em meu celular, eu não sei se está, mas eu abro muita coisa do google, como gmail, chrome e etc. Tem a ver isso?

Comment: @GrupoCDSInformática, quando tento pegar o token eu tenho esse erro: **Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.inet.droid.br. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first. ocorreu**. Diz que firebaseApp não foi inicializada. Como se faz isso? Fui fazendo conforme exemplo. O erro se dá nessa linha: **Log.Debug(TAG, "InstanceID token: " + FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token);**

Comment: Vi que nas propriedades do google-services.json em Ação de Compilação não tenho a opção **GoogleServicesJson**

Comment: A FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) você tem que fazer na Application (falando de Android blz), e o GoogleServices.json não é compilado mesmo. Mas pelo menos nas Apps android, ele vai imbutido.

Comment: Vamos mover a conversa para o [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/66393/minhas-notificacoes-nao-estao-chegando-e-acho-que-meu-codigo-pode-estar-correto), vou te ajudar a resolver o problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> OBS: PASSO A PASSO PARA CONFIGURAÇÃO NO XAMARIN FORMS, PENSANDO NAS CONFIGURAÇÕES DO ANDROID. PARA IOS, POSSO FAZER UM PASSO A PASSO DEPOIS.

Vamos lá, vou moldar a resposta para o tópico. Todo o processo é simples, mas fica difícil de enteder porque muita coisa na documentação é "faz que dá certo".

Então vamos lá.

> Preparando o projeto.

Primeira coisa que precisa fazer é atualizar o SDK e configurar nos Properties do projeto, para apontar para a API correta. Vou mostrar no meu projeto (Xamarin.Forms) como está, nas imagens abaixo. Importantíssimo: Adicione a permissão de internet para o aplicativo.

[image: android.manifest]

[image: Application]

Feito isso, precisamos atualizar os arquivos do nuget. O segredo aqui, é dar um build no projeto depois de mudar as configurações acima, fechar o Visual Studio e abrir novamente, para ele detectar as mudanças (o velho sair do fusca e entrar no fusca).

Atualize tudo o que aparecer, e depois vamos adicionar duas referências: a Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base e o Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging. As outras são adicionadas automaticamente, como dependências.

[image: nuget]

Feito isso, vamos partir para o código.

> Implementação dos códigos.

Vou supor que já tenham criado um projeto no Firebase, adicionado o aplicativo no mesmo. Se não o fez, pode ver o passo a passo [aqui](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/firebase-cloud-messaging/#Setting_Up_Firebase_Cloud_Messaging).

Primeira coisa que temos que acertar, o manifest do projeto. Vou colocar o meu manifest aqui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto" package="br.com.grupoestudos.app1xamarin" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:label="App1.Android" android:icon="@drawable/Icon">

    <receiver
    android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver"
    android:exported="false" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

  </application>
</manifest>
```

Explicando o que acontece por debaixo dos panos. O xamarin vai registrar dois IntentReceivers para poder escutar os eventos do firebase. Como o firebase manda mensagens para o Google Play Services, ele replica a mensagem para os aplicativos. Neste caso, somente o aplicativo corrente vai receber uma mensagem enviado pelo firebase, para o applicationId. Esse valor não precisa mudar pois ele pega do arquivo google-services.json automaticamente.

Falando no arquivo, o segundo passo é pegar o arquivo google-services.json que é feito o download depois de configurar o app no Firebase, e colocar na raiz do projeto android. Em seguida, abra as propriedades do aplicativo e mude o Build Action para GoogleServicesJson. Essa opção somente vai aparecer (se não aparecer de prima), depois de instalar o Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging e fechar e abrir o Visual Studio novamente (é horrivelmente chato ter de fazer isso, e nem sei porque precisa fazer).

[image: google-services.json properties]

Terceiro. Vamos criar uma classe, que implementa FirebaseInstanceIdService. O app vai chamar essa classe sozinha, para poder registrar o app no projeto do Firebase. Ele faz isso automaticamente, lendo e registrando o app por debaixo dos panos.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Firebase.Iid;
using Android.Util;
using Firebase.Messaging;

namespace App1.Droid.Firebase
{
    [Service]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]
    public class MyFirebaseIIDService : FirebaseInstanceIdService
    {
        const string TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";
        public override void OnTokenRefresh()
        {
            var refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
            Log.Debug(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
            SendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
        }
        void SendRegistrationToServer(string token)
        {
            //Neste método, é possível enviar o token para um servidor ou api, atualizando o token do dispositivo.
        }
    }
}
```

Feito isso, podemos rodar o app e ele já vai estar funcionando para mensagens em background (quando o app ta minimizado) somente!!!!!!

Se der um erro na hora de rodar, falando que tem que chamar o FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context);, não se desespere. Dá um clean na solution e faz o build novamente, que o erro some.

> Mensagens em foreground (quando ele ta aberto)

Para que isso funcione, vamos precisar criar mais uma classe, que implementa FirebaseMessagingService. Essa classe vai pegar a mensagem que vem do Firebase, e vai mostrar uma notification do android.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Firebase.Messaging;
using Android.Util;

namespace App1.Droid.Firebase
{
    [Service]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
    public class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
    {
        const string TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
        public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
        {
            Log.Debug(TAG, "From: " + message.From);
            Log.Debug(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + message.GetNotification().Body);

            SendNotification(message.GetNotification().Body);
        }

        void SendNotification(string messageBody)
        {
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

            var notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon)
                .SetContentTitle("FCM Message")
                .SetContentText(messageBody)
                .SetAutoCancel(true)
                .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            var notificationManager = NotificationManager.FromContext(this);
            notificationManager.Notify(0, notificationBuilder.Build());
        }
    }
}
```

> Extra

A mensagem do firebase enviada, ela ou você manda para o aplicativo, ou manda para algum dispositivo. Para não precisar ler os tokens e ficar correndo atrás depois mandando uma mensagem para cada token, existem os topics.

Você pode se inscrever em um tópico, e depois mandar o push para esse tópico, e todos os dispositivos inscritos nele vão receber. Segue abaixo o código da minha MainActivity mostrando a inscrição do tópico. Única coisa, os tópicos demoram um pouco a aparecer no console do firebase, por isso crie todos os tópicos que precisar e já faz a inscrição neles.

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

using Android.Gms.Common;
using Android.Util;
using Firebase.Iid;
using Firebase.Messaging;

namespace App1.Droid
{
    [Activity (Label = "App1", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme="@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        const string TAG = "MainActivity";

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar; 

            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);
            LoadApplication (new App1.App ());

            Log.Debug(TAG, "InstanceID token: " + FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token);

            //Aqui eu me inscrevo no tópico.
            FirebaseMessaging.Instance.SubscribeToTopic("news");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito bom. Já tenho um projeto agora funcionando como falamos, vou implementar isso em outro. É bom para estudos. O GooglePlayService.Base não que instalar no meu xam.forms, mas eu instalo num projeto android apenas, mas vou tentar outra vez. De qualquer forma, sei que o site não gosta disso, mas obrigado!!!

Comment: Cara, não consigo pegar o token. Coloquei um break, a primeira vez parou, mas agora não para e quando eu envio com o token anterior dá erro de token não registrado, significando que o token mudou. A cada build ele altera, mas isso é normal. Vou tentar enviar para o serviço e enviar mensagem por console que eu fiz.

Comment: Usa o método SendRegistrationToServer(string token) para poder enviar para o seu server o token novo, quando ele for gerado. Agora, o push tem uns negocio quando gera em debug tbm que tem hr que pega, hora que não. Em release funciona perfeito. Se for o caso (como acontece comigo), desliga o wifi e liga, ou reinicia o aparelho/emulador.

Comment: cara, não estou conseguindo pegar o token no método SendRegistrationToServer e se pego no MainActivity **FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token** a mensagem que pego quando eu envio uma notificação é: ***Not Registered***. A Server Key está correta, pois eu pego lá no projeto em Cloud Messaging, mas o token, pode não ser este ou é? Então por que a mensagem?